# I get optional value where I mustn't. swift 3.2

Tags: swift, option-type

I was migrating from swift 2.2 to swift 3.2

and some strange behavior occurred, I got optional value where I mustn't.

my code:

```
if let tmpStr = strFromFld?.replacingOccurrences(of: sess.decimalPoint, with: ".") {
            if convType == "buy" {
                print("Why optional here")
                print(tmpStr) //this shows tmpStr is optional 
                print("???")
}
```

[link to picture where Xcode shows tmpStr as optional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHcE5.jpg)

full function, sorry for bad coding, don't laugh ):

```
func updateInfoForSum(_ strFromFld:String?) {
        guard strFromFld != nil else {return}
        if let tmpStr = strFromFld?.replacingOccurrences(of: sess.decimalPoint, with: ".") {
            if convType == "buy" {
                print("Why optional here")
                print(tmpStr)
                print("???")

                infoSumConvert.text = "Сумма " +
                    WalletStuff.doubleToMoneyStr(
                        Double(
                            truncAfter2SymbolAfterDecimalDelimeter(
                                String(
                                    NSString(string: tmpStr).doubleValue / selectedCurrency.saleRate!
                                    ).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: sess.decimalPoint)
                                ).replacingOccurrences(of: sess.decimalPoint, with: ".")
                            )!
                    )
                    + " \(selectedCurrency.name)"
            } else {
                infoSumConvert.text = "Сумма " +
                    WalletStuff.doubleToMoneyStr(
                        Double(
                            truncAfter2SymbolAfterDecimalDelimeter(
                                String(
                                    NSString(string: tmpStr).doubleValue * selectedCurrency.buyRate!
                                    ).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: sess.decimalPoint)
                                ).replacingOccurrences(of: sess.decimalPoint, with: ".")
                            )!
                    )
                    + " UZS"
            }
        }

    }
```

Migrating to swift 4.1 does not help neither ((

Comment: This is a weird behaviour. Have you tried cleaning your build folder?

Comment: Malik, I was thinking wis behavior is a bug of Xcode 9.2 and download Xcode 9.3. but with no effect, and cleaning(Product->Clean) has no effect also.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.2 and haven't faced this problem. The block in your posted code seems to be missing a closing `}` for `if convoType == "buy"`. Is there any more code inside this `if let` block? if so, can you share it?

Comment: On a side note, Xcode 9.3 doesn't have Swift 3.2. instead it will default it to Swift 3.3 (which has its own set of problems)

Comment: @J.Doe It has both 4.1 and 3.3. If your code base is in Swift 3, it will set the Swift version to Swift 3.3

Comment: @Malik, where to share?

Comment: @NMaks Edit the question and add the additional code

Comment: @NMaks Nothing seems to be wrong with the code. Try deleting all of the `Derived Data` and then doing a clean build. See if the issue still persists. On a side note, you don't need the `guard` statement in this scenario. The `if let` will take care of this case

Comment: @Malik, deleting derived data didn't fix the issue :( 
I will try to migrate swift 4, maybe that will fix my issue.

Comment: One possible explanation is that you are passing a String containing "Optionl(...)" as the actual argument of `updateInfoForSum(_:)`. Please show your code where calling `updateInfoForSum(_:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is wrong. `tmpStr` is *not* an Optional String. It is a normal string whose text contains the word “Optional”. The string itself says `"Optional(1000)"` but it is a normal String.